# GA Appending "=" (Equals Sign) to URLs

Tags: google-analytics

Hey I'm not sure why this is happening. GA seems to be randomly appending equals signs to some URL. They are not present in this way on the live site.

I made a fresh view with no filters or other configurations and it still occurs. I've never seen this before and it's very annoying. Any idea what's causing this and or how to fix it? Any idea where to start looking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Admin > [your view] > View Settings you can choose to `Exclude URL Query Parameters` to address this.

Comment: I've dug in a little more. Our URLs occasionally have " & " in the URL which encodes as %20%26%20 in the address bar. GA rewrites this as " & " in it's program, which then tricks it into thinking it's a parameter, so anything after the & is treated as the parameter, then it tacks an = after that. So I can't use that feature because it would exclude actual portions of the URL (there are dozens).